# Set Default Prefix in CakePHP 3 based on sub domain

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to build multiple sub domain which point to same source code of CakePHP v3

Scenario is

1. If domain is "admin.localhost.com" then prefix value should be admin.
2. If domain is "xyz.localhost.com",'abc.localhost.com' or any on sub domain then prefix value should be vendor
3. If domain is "localhost.com" or "www.localhost.com" then prefix value should be false as cakephp 3 have by default.

I have tryied to findout from CakePHP 3 document. but I didint get how to set default prefix.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got Answer of my question myself

We have to set prefix in `config/routs.php` by exploding `HTTP_HOST`

```
$exp_domain= explode(".",env("HTTP_HOST"));

$default_prefix=false; // default prefix is false
if(count($exp_domain)>2 && $exp_domain[0]!="www")
{
    if($exp_domain[0]=="admin") $default_prefix="admin"; 
    else $default_prefix="vendor";
}

if($default_prefix=="admin")
{
    // default routes  for vendor users with base scope and pass prefix as admin ($default_prefix)
    Router::scope('/', function ($routes) use($default_prefix) {
        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'dashboard','prefix'=>$default_prefix]);
        $routes->connect('/:action', ['controller' => 'admins','prefix'=>$default_prefix]);
        $routes->connect('/:controller/:action', ['controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action','prefix'=>$default_prefix]);
        $routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', ['controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action','prefix'=>$default_prefix]);

    });

}
else if($default_prefix=="vendor")
{
    // default routes  for vendor users with base scope and pass prefix as vendor ($default_prefix)
    Router::scope('/', function ($routes) use($default_prefix) {
        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'vendors', 'action' => 'dashboard','prefix'=>$default_prefix]);
        $routes->connect('/:action', ['controller' => 'vendors','prefix'=>$default_prefix]);
        $routes->connect('/:controller/:action', ['controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action','prefix'=>$default_prefix]);
        $routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', ['controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action','prefix'=>$default_prefix]);
    });
}
else
{
    // default routes  for normal users with base scope
    Router::scope('/', function ($routes) use($default_prefix) {
        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard');
        $routes->connect('/:action', ['controller' => 'users');
        $routes->connect('/:controller/:action', ['controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action');
        $routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', ['controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action');
    });
}
```

So main trick is need to pass prefix on root scope.